# Libgdx - Adding a Stage to a Screen structure

Tags: java, android, screen, libgdx, stage

I've been running through various tutorials and introductions to Libgdx. Fairly happy with writing apps in Studio, but now branching into Eclipse and Libgdx for graphics/games.

I've used this tutorial:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game

..and have removed the raindrops/bucket, to then include 100 balls bouncing around the screen using simple vector math.

I've applied some gestures such as zooming (with limitations), panning, and rotating. However, the latter was setup with **If Gdx.input.getX() < 100 Then RotateLeft** and vice-versa **If  Gdx.input.getX()>700 Then RotateRight** [Pseudo]. I wanted to add a button on the screen (any png will suffice for now) and if the touch overlaps with the image, then perform the action. But the image is rotated with the screen, if the screen rotates, when I want it static relative to the camera.

I know that I need to unproject various coodinates to do this, but I've heard a simpler method is just to restructure using Stages and Actors using **Scene2D** as it deals with camera buttons, etc.

From the above Tutorial, is it simple to alter it to include Stages and Actors, or is a complete restructure required? I want to start off in the right direction before I get too far down the wrong route.

Currently the structure I have is:

**Launcher**

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

...

public void create() {
    ...
    this.setScreen(new ScreenMainMenu(this));
}

....

}
```

**Screen: Main Menu**

```
public class ScreenMainMenu implements Screen {

final MyGame game;

OrthographicCamera camera;

//Screen doesn't use create() method so use a constructor
public ScreenMainMenu(final MyGame gam) {
    game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
....

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

        game.setScreen(new ScreenGame(game));
        dispose();
    }


}
```

**Screen: The detailed Game code**

```
public class ScreenGame  implements Screen, GestureListener {
....
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

### It is simple to alter it to include Stages and Actors

I'd suggest you to follow some tutorial for that. Without using actors and stages you'd be missing a lot from libgdx. Libgdx heavily relies on them, so using advanced features would require you to use them. So better learn it first. And it's not difficult at all.

Good luck.

Comment: in my render() method, inbetween my batch.begin and batch.end, I have a for loop for each object (ball) and I batch.draw(ball,x,y). I assume I wouldn't be using one Actor per ball? The Actors are mainly for UI elements (eg titles, buttons, etc), and not involved in the lower screen graphics (the balls bouncing around the screen)? Currently I have 100 balls and in the future it would increase..

Comment: You should make each ball as actors. They can represent entities of any level of abstraction. You don't even need to call `draw` for each of them. Just add them to stage at start and call stage.draw(). All will get drawn.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know whether this higher-level of abstraction, with Actors, would cause a performance issue with 100 or even 1000 Actor objects

Comment: I can't think of a case where more than 100 actors would be all visible and fit in the screen at the same time, but don't worry about the performance. There are things like `ParticleEffect`s in libgdx to handle tiny objects. As long as number of actors is around 100, you shouldn't worry. It might even work for more, I haven't just tested. I'd suggest you to try it first and if performance is a problem, then you can think about optimizations.

Comment: Ok thanks. I wanted to move, say maybe 1000 objects around the screen, but tiny ones. I'd then be able to zoom in and see their sprite. Imagine swarming algorithms for flocks of birds. ParticleEffects seems to be things like an emitter, fire, fireworks, etc. However, each of my particles will have it's own sprite, and move around independently.

Comment: If their motion is almost random, I'd stick to sprites in that case. That's what they are for. You probably don't need higher level functionality provided by actors for each object (like automatic event dispatch, actor groups, hierarchies etc.).